# Bulkify my trigger - Quote Create

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that creates a new quote when a new business opportunity is created, it works very nicely however I have requirement to create multiple quotes when the opportunity is created. 4 quotes for each new opp. Can someone help me achieve this. My current trigger is below:

```
trigger CreateQuote on Opportunity (after insert) {
    List<Id> oppIdsList = new List<Id>();
    List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        oppIdsList.add(o.id);
    }
    Opportunity[] oppList = [SELECT
                                name,
                                id,
                                account.billingStreet,
                                account.billingCity,
                                account.billingState,
                                account.billingCountry
                            FROM Opportunity
                            WHERE id IN :oppIdsList and Type = 'New Client'];
    for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
        Quote q = new Quote();
        q.name = 'Quote-' + o.name;
        q.opportunityId = o.id;
        q.billingStreet = o.account.billingStreet;
        q.billingCity = o.account.billingCity;
        q.billingState = o.account.billingState;
        q.billingCountry = o.account.billingCountry;
        q.ExpirationDate = date.today()+60;
        quoteList.add(q);
    }
    insert quoteList;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with creating 4 quotes in the `for (Opportunity o : oppList)` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be pretty straightforward to implement four quotes instead of 1.

Essentially you'd want to repeat the steps you already have within your iterator `for` loop once per quote.

```
for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
 //start here
    Quote q = new Quote();
    q.name = 'Quote-' + o.name;
    q.opportunityId = o.id;
    q.billingStreet = o.account.billingStreet;
    q.billingCity = o.account.billingCity;
    q.billingState = o.account.billingState;
    q.billingCountry = o.account.billingCountry;
    q.ExpirationDate = date.today()+60;
    quoteList.add(q);
  //repeat to here
}
```

A simple way would be to do like this:

```
for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
    Quote q1 = new Quote();
    q1.name = 'Quote-' + o.name;
    q1.opportunityId = o.id;
    q1.billingStreet = o.account.billingStreet;
    q1.billingCity = o.account.billingCity;
    q1.billingState = o.account.billingState;
    q1.billingCountry = o.account.billingCountry;
    q1.ExpirationDate = date.today()+60;
    quoteList.add(q1);

    Quote q2 = new Quote();
    q2.name = 'Quote-' + o.name;
    q2.opportunityId = o.id;
    ...etc.
    quoteList.add(q2);

    //...repeat ad nauseum

}
```

For the sake of DRY, you'd probably want to make this a bit more friendly by writing yourself a little helper method in a class somewhere with the params you want to set differently for each quote:

```
public class MyHelper{
  public static Quote createQuoteFromOpp(String NameStr, Opportunity o){
    Quote q = new Quote();
    q.opportunitId =  o.id;
    q.name = NameStr + ' ' + o.name;
    //etc...
    return q
}
```

Then you could just invoke it however many times you want...whether several times manually...in a loop...etc.

```
for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
    quoteList.add(MyHelper.createQuoteFromOpp('Quote 1', o));
    quoteList.add(MyHelper.createQuoteFromOpp('Quote 2', o));
    quoteList.add(MyHelper.createQuoteFromOpp('Quote 3', o));
    quoteList.add(MyHelper.createQuoteFromOpp('Quote 4', o));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger looks reasonably bulkified (which means will not break under bulk data loads - doesn't do DML or query in loops).

What you need is an additional for() loop inside your `for (Opportunity o : oppList)` loop:

`for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    [create quote & add to list here] }`